# Select using LEFT OUTER JOIN with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **Table A** and **Table B**

**Table A**

```
1. *id*
2. *name*
```

**Table B**

```
1. *A.id*
2. *datetime*
```

I want to select

```
1. *A.id*
2. *A.name*
3. *B.datetime*
```

Even if table B do not contains a row with *A.id* for specific day and it should replace that column with *NULL*

e.g

*Table A* contains

```
1. *(1 , Haris)*
2. *(2, Hashsim)*
```

*Table B* Contains following for today's date.

```
1. *(1, '2014-12-26 08:00:00')*
```

I should show 2 results with id **1** and **2** instead of only id **1**.

Using LEFT OUTER JOIN with WHERE Clause makes it a LEFT INNER JOIN, how to work around that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**LEFT OUTER JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to get all the rows from `Left table` and one that does not have match will have `NULL` values in `Right table` columns

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.name,
       B.[datetime]
FROM   tableA A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB B
                    ON A.Id = B.id
                       AND B.[datetime] < @date
```

Comment: If I add WHERE to the query for specific date time it will only show that are present,

e.g. WHERE B.datetime <= 'myDateTime' it will give results for those which have the id in Table B. What to do about that

Comment: @HarisMehmood Yes thats how it works by giving where clause `WHERE B.datetime <= 'myDateTime'` you **converting** `left join` to `inner join`

Comment: Yeah i figured that out it was obvious, is there a work around ?

Comment: @HarisMehmood change `left Join` **on condition** `..tableA A Left outer join tableB B on A.Id = B.id and b.datetime < @date.. `

Comment: @HarisMehmood - Updated the answer, btw you should update your question with condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, b.datetime
FROM A
LEFT Outer JOIN B on B.id = A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.datetime
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on B.aid = a.id
WHERE coalesce(B.datetie, '1900-01-01') < @MyDateTime
```

Comment: I want it on specific date, if I add WHERE B.datetime <= 'my datetime'
it only gives results that are present in table B.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.id,A.name,B.datetime 
from tableA A 
Left join
(
   SELECT B.ID,B.datetime 
   FROM tableB B
   WHERE B.datetime <= 'myDateTime'
)B
ON A.aid = B.id
```